# Increasing the height on inline block elements together?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to develop a webpage with three div elements with varying widths. I am using the below snippet to do so .

---

page1.html

---

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left_pane>Left Pane</div>
<div id="main_pane">Main Pane</div>
<div id="right_pane>Right Pane</div>
</div>
```

---

page1.css

---

```
#wrapper{
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 12px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    width: 100%;

}

#left_pane{
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: -6px;

}

#main_pane{

        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-right: -6px;
}

#right_pane{

        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-right: -6px;
}
```

The problem is that while this works fine, in the main pane I have source of dynamic content and when it increases I want other divs to increase there size as well, but none of them are increasing with increase in content. Can anyone please help me with the same ?

( I also tried using display:table-cell but for that I cannot specify the separate width, as I want each div to be of a specified width )

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What happened when you tried to specify width for the table-cell attempt? You should be able to define width for table-cell display which is probably the easy way to make the height increase at the same time

Comment: There is a mistake in your code. in `HTML`, the id name is `left_pane` and in `css` it is `#left-pane`. Same thing is happened with other `divs`

Comment: Hi, I tried Again with the table cell property but now I placed in wrapper {display:table} property and the width seems to be okay but now the height gets messed up. I want them to cover the whole area of the container in terms of height. Link To Updated fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/zQxEZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `white-space: nowrap;` and add `word-wrap: break-word;`

```
#wrapper{
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/zQxEZ/)

Comment: I am talking about the change in height. The demo you have provided shows 3 divs with different heights. I want them to have same height. Can it be done keeping control over the width of these div tags ?